# Ubuntu 14.04 Won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 14.04, system-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu for some time but it won't boot at all. I followed the instructions on the Ubuntu website to make a bootable USB drive (I used Pen-Drive-Linux ). Then I changed the boot order (the BIOS sees the USB) but it fails to boot from it. I even tried unplugging my hard drive and it still doesn't see it.

I have an ASRock 960GC-GS motherboard. Windows can see the files just fine but it wont boot. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You may wish to search for this answer, as it is very common. Look through [this list](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot?sort=frequent&pageSize=15)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Unetbootin** (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to burn ISO to USB Flash Disk. You can see the example tutorial in here http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/usb (Windows) and here http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Bootable-Ubuntu-with-USB-Drive-Using-UNetbootin (Ubuntu). The Google keyword is **unetbootin bootable ubuntu**. I always successfully burn Ubuntu (even Hiren's Boot CD) by using Unetbootin.